# 3D Space Binning with Intersecting Sphere

Tags: python, data-structures, hash

I am counting the number of collisions of a very large number of particles, and I want to divide the space with many spheres, intersecting one with the other.

I have already managed to divide the space in cubes. By taking the coordinates of the particles, dividing them with the cube size and flooring them, I then compute the number of collisions. In the 2D case:

```
given x_coordinate and y_coordinate
xi = math.floor(x_coordinate/cube_size)
yi = math.floor(y_coordinate/cube_size)
for each particle belonging to the same cube:
compute probability of collision
```

I want now to divide the space in spheres, by circumscribing the sphere to the cube, like this (2D case for simplicity): [2D binning with circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g3Vg.png).

The problem is that now the spheres intersecate, so it is way too complex with respect to the cubes division. On the other hands the solution given with the cube is very elegant and I want to find a way to exploit it for the sphere approach.

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code

Comment: If you are prepared to skew your coordinate system to non-orthogonal axes then there is a fairly cute way to do approximately what you want by making the layers like those of hexagonal close packed spheres (and increase the radius if you want them overlapping).

Comment: @MartinBrown Interesting. Do you have some references?

Comment: There is a bit about the [2D hexagonal efficient coordinate grid case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_Efficient_Coordinate_System) on Wiki. I can't see anything obvious about the 3D version in a quick online search. The advantage over a rectangular grid is that you have identical nearest neighbours but indexing them gets quite tricky.